# Always Almost vs Almost Always

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, difference, word-order

Is there any difference between:

> 1. I **always almost** burn myself when I cook.
> 2. I **almost always** burn myself when I cook.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is a difference:

> 1. You *nearly* burn yourself *every time* you cook

> 2. You *burn* yourself *nearly every time* you cook

So the first means you nearly burn yourself all the time, but it does not actually happen. The second implies you *do* burn yourself, and nearly all the time.

Answer (score 3):

DialFrost's answer is correct. I'm adding why.

As with most adverbs in English, "almost" modifies whatever comes *after* it.

> 1. I always [almost burn] myself when I cook.
> 2. I [almost always] burn myself when I cook.

Comment: +1 Thanks for adding on!